# Installing PHP 7.2 on Centos 7 for Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, linux, laravel, centos7, php-7.2

I'm attempting to install PHP 7.2 for an app I've developed on a homestead box.  I'm using centos 7.  I've installed PHP 7.2, git, composer, etc.  When I run composer install in my app's parent folder I get:

[image: composer errors]

Even though I've added php7.2-mbstring it still gives me the error above.

```
sudo yum install php72-php-mbstring
```

I've tried to add 5.4's mbstring via `sudo yum install php-mbstring`

I'm not finding any success there either.  See below.

[image]

Comment: Can you run `phpenmod` on CentOS?

Comment: Try `php72w-mbstring`.

Comment: I don't have access to phpenmod. @Michiel It tells me it cannot find the package php72w-mbstring.

Answer (score 2):

This should help

```
sudo yum install php7.2-dom 
sudo yum install php-mbstring
```

In that order